# MS Access: when working with Continuous Forms, how can I run a query that filters by ID of each record and display result in Textbox?

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2016

### Here is my scenario:

I have a database for projects I manage. In this database, I have a table for Projects (tblProjects) and a table for Hot Notes (tblHotNotes) that look like this:

> **tblProjects:**
>
> - ProjectID
> - ProjectName

> **tblHotNotes:**
>
> - HotNoteID
> - ProjectID *(fk)*
> - HotNote
> - HotNoteDate

I also have a continuous form called **frmProjectList** that lists all projects and displays their info. In this form, I display the **ProjectID** in a Textbox called **txtProjectID** and I have another Textbox called **HotNotes_Textbox** where I want to show the **CONCAT_SQL** function return.

I found and adapted a VBA Function that runs a query, formats the results, and returns it as a string:

```
Public Function CONCAT_SQL(strSQL As String) As String

   Dim r As ADODB.Recordset
   Dim a1 As Variant
   Set l = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")
   Dim s As String
   Dim outer As Long

   Set r = New ADODB.Recordset
   r.Open strSQL, CurrentProject.Connection, 1

   a1 = r.GetRows()
       
   For outer = LBound(a1, 2) To UBound(a1, 2)
        s = s + CStr("<b>" & a1(2, outer) & "</b>: " & a1(1, outer) & "<br>")
   Next

   CONCAT_SQL = s

End Function
```

When the  **frmProjectList** loads, the Sub below is called and the **CONCAT_SQL** function is called within it. The SQL query is defined here:

```
Private Sub Form_Load()

    Me.HotNotes_Textbox = CONCAT_SQL("SELECT [ProjectName], tblHotNotes.HotNote, tblHotNotes.HotNoteDate FROM tblProjects INNER JOIN tblHotNotes ON tblProjects.ProjectID = tblHotNotes.ProjectID WHERE tblHotNotes.ProjectID = " & Me.txtProjectID)
     
End Sub
```

### Problem

When I Open **frmProjectList** it shows all records as expected but the **HotNotes_Textbox** Textbox shows in all records only the **results of the query for the first record**. i.e. tblHotNotes.ProjectID = 1 as opposed to having tblHotNotes.ProjectID changing for each record.

[image: Continuous Form picture with repeting values in HotNotes_Texbox]

Is there a way to fix this and have different results showing in the HotNotes_Texbox?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call function from textbox ControlSource, don't set textbox value with VBA.

I doubt you need to include tblProjects in the SQL.

```
=CONCAT_SQL("SELECT HotNote, HotNoteDate FROM tblHotNotes WHERE ProjectID = " & [txtProjectID])
```

Comment: This worked! Thank you!
Now I will just have to change my function to handle projects that don't have hot notes.

Comment: The array object is not necessary. Can just loop through recordset, but only if there are records. `Do While Not r.EOF`. Don't forget to use `r.MoveNext`.